# Is there a way to use my 360 controller as a DirectInput controller on my PC?

Tags: windows-7, game-controller, controller, xinput

For example, in old games that don't support XInput, I can't use my 360 controller. It won't recognise the analogue sticks or triggers (I just want to recognise them as buttons, not triggers).

Is there a way to get games (or Windows) to treat my 360 controller as an older DirectInput controller, so I can re-assign buttons correctly?

Answer (score 2):

According to Microsoft, Xbox 360 Controllers [should work with DirectInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417014(v=vs.85).aspx).   There is however a caveat:

> The left and right trigger buttons will act as a single button, not independently